# use JSON column or a separate table to store a list of things of the same type in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

A User can have many Posts, I'm wondering whether I should store the ids of the Posts in a JSON column in the User table or I should create a separate table with composite primary key(user_id, post_id)?

If there are 10 million user, and each user has 100 posts, the separate table method will have 1 billion records, this doesn't seem very good for scaling or efficient.

Which method would be the better choice in this case? Does one have better performance than the other?

Comment: I'm not a NoSQL guru (nor a MySQL guru), but your problem very much seems similar to what Twitter and Facebook face daily.  I know that they use NoSQL databases like Cassandra, so maybe you should look into this as well.

Comment: I think at the point that a site reaches 10 million users, it's reasonable to seek professional help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you query the data. For example, do you ever need to fetch an individual post out of the list for a user? Or do anything else besides treat the full list of posts as one string? If so, then do not use JSON; use the separate table.

MySQL can actually support billions of rows in a table. I was responsible for one database at my last job that had over 5 billion rows. We used a mix of partitioning and indexing to help queries.

That said, I will say that *any* website with 10 million active users does not use just one MySQL Server instance for all the data. They split the data over many instances.

How to split data in this way has to be done very carefully, though. Do it only after you know exactly how your data will be queried. And after you have done everything else possible to optimize the database for the queries you run (indexing, caching, etc.).

[Scalable Internet Architectures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067232699X) is a difficult, complex topic. There is no single, simple answer like "JSON vs. separate table" that will solve all your problems. There are many ways you can solve different bottlenecks of scalability.